# Sending mails from localhost to gmail or yahoo or rediff?

Tags: php, javascript

i am working on sending email to any recipient like yahoo gmail 
my code is
contact form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Email Form </title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="sendeail.php">

<!-- DO NOT change ANY of the php sections -->
<?php
$ipi = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$httprefi = getenv ("HTTP_REFERER");
$httpagenti = getenv ("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
?>

<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $ipi ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="httpref" value="<?php echo $httprefi ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="httpagent" value="<?php echo $httpagenti ?>" />


Your Name: <br />
<input type="text" name="visitor" size="35" />
<br />
Your Email:<br />
<input type="text" name="visitormail" size="35" />
<br /> <br />
<br />
Attention:<br />
<select name="attn" size="1">
<option value=" Sales n Billing ">Sales n Billing </option> 
<option value=" General Support ">General Support </option> 
<option value=" Technical Support ">Technical Support </option> 
<option value=" Webmaster ">Webmaster </option> 
</select>
<br /><br />
Mail Message:
<br />
<textarea name="notes" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Send Mail" />
<br />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and senemail.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Sendemail Script</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Reminder: Add the link for the 'next page' (at the bottom) --> 
<!-- Reminder: Change 'YourEmail' to Your real email --> 

<?php

$ip = $_POST['ip']; 
$httpref = $_POST['httpref']; 
$httpagent = $_POST['httpagent']; 
$visitor = $_POST['visitor']; 
$visitormail = $_POST['visitormail']; 
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$attn = $_POST['attn'];


if (eregi('http:', $notes)) {
die ("Do NOT try that! ! ");
}
if(!$visitormail == "" && (!strstr($visitormail,"@") || !strstr($visitormail,"."))) 
{
echo "<h2>Use Back - Enter valid e-mail</h2>\n"; 
$badinput = "<h2>Feedback was NOT submitted</h2>\n";
echo $badinput;
die ("Go back! ! ");
}

if(empty($visitor) || empty($visitormail) || empty($notes )) {
echo "<h2>Use Back - fill in all fields</h2>\n";
die ("Use back! ! "); 
}

$todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;

$attn = $attn ; 
$subject = $attn; 

$notes = stripcslashes($notes); 

$message = " $todayis [EST] \n
Attention: $attn \n
Message: $notes \n 
From: $visitor ($visitormail)\n
Additional Info : IP = $ip \n
Browser Info: $httpagent \n
Referral : $httpref \n
";

$from = "From: $visitormail\r\n";


mail("YourEmail", $subject, $message, $from);

?>

<p align="center">
Date: <?php echo $todayis ?> 
<br />
Thank You : <?php echo $visitor ?> ( <?php echo $visitormail ?> ) 
<br />

Attention: <?php echo $attn ?>
<br /> 
Message:<br /> 
<?php $notesout = str_replace("\r", "<br/>", $notes); 
echo $notesout; ?> 
<br />
<?php echo $ip ?> 

<br /><br />
<a href="contact.php"> Next Page </a> 
</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

what changes i have to made in my localhost so that i would be able to send the mail...

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to do the actual email composition/sending. Beyond that, you'll either have to run an SMTP server locally, or have access to one elsewhere (your ISP's?, google's?) to handle the physical sending of the email.

Comment: Also you will need to be familiar with RFC 822 if you intend on sending these messages yourself.  The headers need to be properly formatted along with the message body.  Gmail, yahoo, etc will all toss your email into spam unless you make an effort to properly format messages. 

PHPMailed will be a good choice if you are not concerned about how to properly format a message.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to [setup an smtp server](http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html) for mail() in php.ini in order to run.

if you're just testing your scripts localy (not in a production server), using your ISP's SMTP will do the trick.

Comment: Not completely true; you can use any SMTP server, such as google, e.g. http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server

Comment: True, I just suggested to use ISP's SMTP :)